# Regions plugin from wavesurfer.js is not working at all

Tags: javascript, html, plugins, waveform, wavesurfer.js

I'm trying to use the Regions plugin from `wavesurfer.js`, but for some reason it's not working. I already tried different approaches I found on some websites, however to no result.
Here is the code:

```
const initializeWavesurfer = () => {
    return WaveSurfer.create({
        container: "#waveform",
        responsive: true,
        height: 80,
        waveColor: "indigo",
        progressColor: "purple"
})
}

const wavesurfer = initializeWavesurfer();

var RegionsPlugin = window.WaveSurfer.regions;

wavesurfer.addPlugin(RegionsPlugin.create({
    regionsMinLength: 2,
    regions: [
        {
            start: 1,
            end: 3,
            loop: false,
            color: 'hsla(400, 100%, 30%, 0.5)'
        }, {
            start: 5,
            end: 7,
            loop: false,
            color: 'hsla(200, 50%, 70%, 0.4)',
            minLength: 1,
            drag:true
        }
    ],
    dragSelection: {
        slop: 5
    }
})).initPlugin('regions');
```

The `wavesurfer.js`and the `waversufer.regions.js` tags are in the `head` in the `HTML` file like this:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/wavesurfer.js@5.2.0/dist/wavesurfer.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/wavesurfer.js/dist/plugin/wavesurfer.regions.js"></script>
```

When I try running it, I get these 2 warnings in the browser:

> webaudio.js:76 The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page.

> webaudio.js:234 [Deprecation] The ScriptProcessorNode is deprecated. Use AudioWorkletNode instead.

Do you have any ideas as to why this isn't working or what could I do to make it work?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I am a little late but I had the same error but I am using the microphone plugin.
You need to put this before the audio start:-

```
wavesurfer.backend.ac.resume();
```

Comment: 12 days isn't late. And such as the objective of stackoverflow is to provide a full question/answer wiki, it's perfect !